# how to set up kernel debugger with visual studio on virtual machine

Tags: c++, debugging, kernel, virtual-machine

i am now learning to debug kernel driver on virtual machine.

I am using virutalbox and i set it up like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIAQk.png

i also installed WDK test target set up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZkfn.png

then i set up the bcdedit commands on the VM and restart the vm:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqprR.png

i tried to configure my vm driver device on visual studio like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9qkR.png

but the status was "unvailable".

The "network hostname" i entered was the ipv4 of the virtualbox adapter found with ipconfig on my host pc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/of4Gw.png

in my view, i think the hostname/ip isnt the expected one so it caused the problem:https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAlDN.png

Where should i get the hostname/ip address in order to make it connect?

I am trying to connect virtual machine to my visual studio kernel debugger with the serial port method.
My process is following a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6p-Kt-Cx9E

i expect the driver test configuration status to be "available" instead of "inavailable".

Comment: I managed to do this using Ethernet connection with static IP. For example, host Virual Box adapter is configured with 192.168.56.1, and guest Ethernet adapter 192.168.56.2. Now you can set `bcdedit /dbdsettings net hostip:192.168.56.1` I used this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug-universal-drivers---step-by-step-lab--echo-kernel-mode-

Comment: i succeeded setting up bridged network on virtual box ,then configuring bcdedit using your command. Connecting to host virtualbox adapter and setting up PCI bus thing with bcdedit. Successfully connected to my windbg on host machine. But i want to achieve code debugging with visual studio , as i am allowed to interact with my codes and breakpoints. But can windbg set breakpoints for driver and debug the driver with source too ? thx!

Comment: Of course, everything is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug-universal-drivers---step-by-step-lab--echo-kernel-mode- Debug Universal Drivers - Step by Step Lab (Echo Kernel-Mode)

Comment: but debugging on virtual machine is different from debugging a remote pc. I cant seem to make the debugging set up work

Comment: Can you show me how i can debug a kernel driver on virtual machine together with the driver source code? thx !